# Missing Option tab in tools?

Tags: modeling

I'm missing my options tab in the tools. I've reset the interface to default and also tried opening previous files that I know I used the options tab, but still no luck. I have no Idea where it went? Can anyone help, cheers!
[image]

Comment: maybe you just need to switch to edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to *Edit* mode by pressing Tab
**Options** tab appears for **Edit** mode.